# jQuery tabs, nesting other jquery elements or javascript within only works on first tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, jcarousel

So I am using jQuery tabs as seen here http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs with just calls to ui.js and ui_002.js. Tabs work great I can set content and all works beautifully. My problem comes from wanting to use jcarousel within each tab.

jCarousel works flawlessly in the first tab, but when you click the next tab, images don't load and carousel won't work. This seems to hold true for all javascript I use. Putting simple things to test like js based rollovers work in first tab but none of the consecutive ones.

I am using this to call the tabs and carousel

```
 jQuery.noConflict();

                jQuery(function() {
                    jQuery('.container-1 > ul').tabs();
                    jQuery('.mycarousel').jcarousel();
                });
```

I am hoping it is something simple, like something I forgot. Thanks in advance and feel free to let me know what else I can supply

Answer (score 1):

The trick lies in the CSS. Instead of using

```
.ui-tabs-hide
  {display:none;}
```

you need to use

```
 .ui-tabs-hide {
        position: absolute;
        left: -10000px;
    }
```